# django makemigrations ValueError

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am learning django. When I type `python manage.py makemigrations`, it shows error in the picture.

[image]

The error message is strange for me. Because like `blog.userinfo` is my     previous project's models content. When I create a new project and try `makemigrations` the error will appear. `models.py` is empty in the new project

Why I have this error? How can I solve this problem.

Comment: raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))
ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to
'blog.userinfo', but app 'blog' isn't installed.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: @yuyang1992, also, don't use comments for adding details to the question. Please Edit the question to add clarifications.

Comment: sorry ,i just sign in stackoverflow , i am not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `blog` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py`.

Your app blog is not detected by Django.

Comment: maybe i express not clearly,i create a new project,but like 'blog' exists in my ppvious project. In the new projcet there is no blog application and models.py is empty ,i guess tht previous project have influence  on  the action that 'makemigrations'

Comment: It's impossible another project is affecting a new django project